# phpMyAdmin relation view is not available

Tags: view, phpmyadmin, relation

For a university project I need to implement a database, and for the CMS we are using WordPress. Now I am trying to add some entities and set foreign keys, but I can't make phpMyAdmin display the "relation view" for the WordPress database, and unfortunately I can't write the proper code to set the foreign key.

How do I access the "relation view" in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 7):

If your table is under the InnoDB storage engine, you will find "Relation view" by opening the Structure page for this table.

If not (for example for the MyISAM storage engine), you need to install the "phpMyAdmin configuration storage" (see http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage) and then you'll find "Relation view" by opening the Structure page for this table. In this case you'll be able to set "internal relations" which are not exactly foreign keys.

Comment: @user2745423 if Marc's answer was helpful, you should mark it as such. (You may wish to refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Kind regards.